# how to send two parameters in <anchor > href for downloading file?

Tags: servlets, download, href

Ex: i try to send single parameter , now i need to send two parameter with request body

so how to achieve this or "how to send filepath via request body to servlet"

`out.println(" <a href=Download?filename="+map.get("filename")+">Download</a>");`

Comment: Please provide more context, e.g. I assume you are using Java. If your example is already working partly, please show those related code parts, e.g. how you defined your map variable, and how you read the filename parameter. If you are following a tutorial, link to that tutorial. If your question is not Java related but HTML in general, as I assume, try to make it more general. Defining parameters in URL paths is not specific to Java, anchor tags or href attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Query string (i.e. the part of URL after '?') can contain multiple parameters. Separate them with '&'. Example:

```
out.println(" <a href=Download?filename="+map.get("filename")+"&filepath="+map.get("filepath")+">Download</a>");
```

[Wikipedia entry on query strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).